# App Maker query multiple values and assign to another value

Tags: google-app-maker

I have multiple locations with multiple issues that can be resolved. Depending on the location and issue the ticket will be routed to a specific tech. I'm not sure how to either query or filter multiple locations, multiple issues, to multiple techs. Example: Location 1, Computer issue, sent to computer tech. Location 1, wiring issue, sent to wiring tech.

Comment: Please share your DB relation details as well

Comment: I have a helpdesk db with only one relation. The relation is for a notes field which enables the technicians to add notes to the tickets. No other relations exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's what you get with this solution (GIF):** [Assign Issues to Techs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHVDr.gif)

First you need to set relations to your models so you can query by filters and "assign" issues to Techs per its type and location. Your model relations would look like this:

One **Issue** to One **Location** 
Many **Issues** to One **Tech**

You then create Issues and associate Locations and Techs with the [Forms](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/data-widgets) widget.
If you want to automatically assign an issue to a Tech per a criteria, you'll have to replace the default "Create New Item" onClick function on the Forms Button with another function. You can change associations with a client script or server script. See documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/relations). Try this client script I made:

```
function createAssignIssuePublic(){

  // Datasources declaration
  var issuesDatasource = app.datasources.Issues;
  var locationDatasource = app.datasources.Locations;

  // Creates an Issue item(record) and after it's finished a Tech is associated to it.
  // Notice the callback function.
  issuesDatasource.createItem(function(record){

    var techsDatasource = app.datasources.Techs;

    // Create a query.
    var techsQuery = techsDatasource.query;

    var issue = issuesDatasource.item;
    var location = issue.Location.Name;

    // Setting the conditionals to assign Tech per issue and location
    if (issue.Type == "Computer issue"){

      // Query by filter (name equals)
      techsQuery.filters.Name._equals = "Computer Tech";

      // Reloads Tech datasource per previous query filter. 
      // Once loaded, it relates the tech item to the issue item/record.
      techsDatasource.load(function(){
        var relatedTech = techsDatasource.item;

        // Changes the Associated Tech
        record.Tech = relatedTech;
      });
  }

  // If issue is "Wiring issue" but NOT in a "Critical Location"
  else if (issue.Type == "Wiring issue" && location !== "Critical Location"){

      techsQuery.filters.Name._equals = "Wiring Tech";

      techsDatasource.load(function(){
        var relatedTech = techsDatasource.item;                  
        record.Tech = relatedTech;
      });
  }

  // If issue is "Wiring issue" but IN in a "Critical Location"
  else if (issue.Type == "Wiring issue" && location == "Critical Location"){

      techsQuery.filters.Name._equals = "Tech Lead";

      techsDatasource.load(function(){
        var relatedTech = techsDatasource.item;
        record.Tech = relatedTech;            
      });
  }

  else{} });}
```

What makes the last table to show issues by the Tech selected, is that the Dropdown widget has a value of `@datasources.Issues.query.filters.Tech._equals` and it reloads the Issues Datasource onValueChange.